# Figure out how much tax was withheld without form 1042-S

Tags: united-states, income-tax, withholding

I haven't received form 1042-S for 2019 from a company that withheld tax on my behalf. They say they mailed it but I haven't got it and I haven't had much luck following up with them to send it again.

I have an SSN (used to be a US resident). Is there a government website where I can check how much was withheld in my name?

Comment: Did you receive a series of checks or only one from the company? Did those payments come with any sort of stub?

Comment: They are a sort of commission paid half-yearly. Incredibly, their commission statements website has been under "renovation" for some time.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe. A [wage and income transcript](https://www.irs.gov/individuals/tax-return-transcript-types-and-ways-to-order-them) is claimed to cover 'information returns ... **such as** W-2, 1099, 1098 and 5498 ...' (emphasis added). Those are the information returns usually of interest to a 'domestic' (citizen or resident) taxpayer, but 1042-S definitely is considered an information return (see e.g. pub 1179) so logically it should be included, although I can't say for certain.

According to NTA a while back, only about 1/3 of people who try pass the security checks for IRS online applications -- and presumably most or nearly all of them are residents -- so I'd say your chances of online (thus immediate) access are not great, but it doesn't hurt to try. It appears the online-to-mail option doesn't support this type, so you may have to download form 4506T and mail or fax it in, after which processing and sending paper will probably take a few weeks.  Good luck.

Comment: Great answer. Thank you. You were right though about it catering to domestics only. When I tried to create an account it says I need to have a valid US credit or debit card and an active US mobile phone number in my name to receive a verification code!